# Is there a way to configure Cpython interpreter's view of system memory

Tags: memory, cpython

I am running a python program on an embedded system. Based on the EC2 instance type, the amount of memory available would vary. I would like to limit the amount of memory my python program uses by limiting the amount of physical memory that is exposed to the python interpreter.

Based on running the program on different instance types it seems that the interpreter looks at the amount of physical memory available and pre-allocates pools or grows the heap ?

Limiting physical memory exposed to the interpreter would help keep the memory footprint lower.

The base operating system is NetBSD, so cgroups or equivalent support does not seem to exist.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the interpreter just using the available memory? Does the behaviour change if 'ulimit' is used to restrict the available memory?

Comment: My bad. The issue was memory fragmentation. Looking at the interpreter's code it does not look like it checks for the available memory. I ended up reworking my code to use preallocated bytearray buffers to process data and this seems to be performing well.

Comment: Using ulimit to restrict the memory usage changes the behavior. The program runs into MemoryError exceptions when the set limit is reached. Thank you for looking at the question.